# About a differential form in submanifolds of hyperboloid diffeomorphics to $S^1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Let
$$\omega=xz\,dx+yz\,dy-z^2\,dz$$
be a $1$-form in $\Bbb{R}^3$ and let $H$ be the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$. I want to show that, if $M\subset H$ is a surface that is diffeomorphic to the sphere $S^1$, so $\int_M \omega=0.$

My idea is to find a $0$-form $\eta$ such that, in $M$, $d\eta=\omega$. My first try was

$$\eta=z\frac{x^2}{2}+z\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{3}\implies  d\eta=xz\,dx+yz\,dy+\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-2z^2}{2}\right)\, dz $$

My hope was to use $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ in the equation of $d\eta$ to cancel some terms and get $d\eta=\omega$, but I didn't get it.

What can I do?

Comment: You mean $M$ is a *curve* diffeomorphic to the *circle* $S^1$. :) But, in fact, as you found out, any compact curve with boundary, of course contained in $H$, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since

\begin{align}
\omega &= z x\, dx + zy\, dy - z^2\, dz\\
&= z( x\, dx + y\, dy - z\, dz ) \\
&=\frac{z}{2} d (x^2 +y^2 -z^2), 
\end{align}

$\omega$ restricts to the zero 1-form on $H$. Then of course $\int _M \omega = 0$.

Comment: So, the condition "diffeomorphic to sphere" is no relevant?

Comment: Yes, it is not relevant in this special case. @MateusRocha